# Opening a file pointer for logging macro in header file

Tags: c, logging, driver, file-pointer

I'm trying to design a logging framework for use in a large C board driver, in which I log specific categories of occurences: Events, Notifications, Control Messages, etc.

Currently I have the logging within the file, driven by a function that opens a file pointer, and writes a specific statement to the file based on a switch statement that switches on an input argument that describes the type.

```
    158 static FILE * fptr = NULL;
    159 void log_to_file(const char *str, int type)
    160 {
    161     if(fptr == NULL)
    162     {
    163         fptr = fopen("file.txt", "a+");
    164     }
    165 
    166     if (fptr == NULL)
    167     {
    168         printf("Error opening file!\n");
    169     }
    170     else
    171     {
    172 
    173         switch (type)
    174         {
    175             case 1: //EVENT 
    176                 fprintf(fptr, "[%s] [EVENT] %s\n", get_time(), str);
    177                 fflush(fptr);
    178                 break;
    179             case 2: //NOTIFICATION
    180                 fprintf(fptr, "[%s] [NOTIF] %s\n", get_time(), str);
    181                 fflush(fptr);
    182                 break;
    183             case 3: //CTRL
    184                 fprintf(fptr, "[%s] [CTRL] %s\n", get_time(), str);
    185                 fflush(fptr);
    186                 break;
    187             default:
    188                 fprintf(fptr, "[%s] [UNRECOGNIZED] %s\n", get_time(), str);
    189                 fflush(fptr);
    190                 break;
```

Then I call this functions using these macros:

```
 32 #define log_event(str) log_to_file(str, 1)
 33 #define log_notif(str) log_to_file(str, 2)
 34 #define log_ctrl(str) log_to_file(str, 3)
```

However, every time that I call this function during runtime, I would have to resolve the switch statement during runtime, which would slow down my code by *an amount* even though it would probably be negligable.

Preferably, I would like to split up each case into a separate function that I could call using a macro in a header file, that could already solve the cases for logging by the time preprocessing is done. This way I could call each case when I need to and not have to process the type. However, is this the right path? I already have a framework that does this and prints to stdout, but opening a file pointer complicates doing all this in a header file and calling the functions from there.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why use a macro? Why not just define separate functions for `log_event`, `log_notif`, `log_ctrl`?

Comment: Why use a switch? Put the type strings in an array, and use `fprintf(fptr, "[%s] [%s] %s\n", get_time(), typestrings[type], str);`

Comment: Or make the string a parameter: `#define log_event(str) log_to_file(str, "EVENT")`

Comment: Worrying about the time it takes to resolve the switch is nonsense. each of the `f*` calls will be much much more expensive.

Comment: What does opening the file pointer have to do with the question?

Comment: @melpomene Using a macro allows me to hide the file manipulation entirely from the file itself, and it also allows me to manipulate logging entirely from one place, such as changing a constant in the header to disable the logging.

Comment: @PSkocik This is a device driver, worrying about all aspects of code efficiency is necessary even when other parts may not be efficient.

Comment: @Dupontrocks11 But all your file manipulation is already in your `log_to_file` function. The macro doesn't buy you anything.

Comment: @Dupontrocks11 IDK, benchmarking `fputs('x',stdout); fflush(stdout);` redirected to a pipe gives me over 1µs per iteration. A switch  like that should take less than 1% of that. I'm normally a pretty obsessive premature optimizer who's in denial about it but this looks like premature optimization to me.

Answer (score 0):

Make the type a string parameter rather than an integer, and then substitute it with `fprintf`.

```
158 static FILE * fptr = NULL;
159 void log_to_file(const char *str, const char *type)
160 {
161     if(fptr == NULL)
162     {
163         fptr = fopen("file.txt", "a+");
164     }
165 
166     if (fptr == NULL)
167     {
168         printf("Error opening file!\n");
169     }
170     else
171     {
            fprintf(fptr, "[%s] [%s] %s\n", get_time(), type, str);
            fflush(fptr);
        }
```

BTW, you should probably make `fptr` local to the function, not a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

I say it's ineffective premature optimization but here you go. No time spent on selecting the category whatsoever:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
static FILE *fptr;
#define MK_LOG(Lower,Upper) \
    void log_##Lower(char const *str){ \
        fptr = fptr ? fptr : fopen("file.txt", "a+"); \
        if(!fptr) printf("Error opening file!\n");  \
        else { fprintf(fptr, "[%s] [" #Upper "] %s\n", get_time(), str); fflush(fptr); } \
    } 

char const* get_time(void) { return "now"; }
MK_LOG(event,EVENT)
MK_LOG(notif,NOTIF)
MK_LOG(ctrl,CTRL)
int main()
{
    log_event("an event");
    log_notif("a notif");
    log_ctrl("a ctrl");
    system("cat file.txt");
}
```